# Recurly js v3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, recurly

I am new to Recurly, I have setup a simple implementation to build on here http://unzipped.wpengine.com/recurly-integrate/ (you can see everything, it is html and a js file called recurly-integration.js which is added straight after the main recurly.js file.

I get this error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined` from recurly.js - seems to be coming from the Pricing.reset function ???

Any help gratefully received as I have been trying to fix it for ages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who might be having the same problem the solution was this:

in my recurly-integration.js I was doing like so:

```
var pricing = new recurly.Pricing();
```

Changing it to:

```
var pricing = recurly.Pricing();
```

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Always feel free to contact support.recurly.com, we're pretty helpful and fast - I hate to hear that you've been debugging for ages without our help!

Running the browser error console, I'm seeing quite a few errors. As a test it would be best to run the
Recurly.js bare minimum (no pun intended- https://docs.recurly.com/js/#examples) and see if the error(s) re-occur. Then gradually add other elements and keep testing by monitoring the browser errors.

Hope you get this resolved soon!

Comment: Hi Rachel - thanks - I actually solved it- I was doing pricing = new recurly.Pricing() - taking away the new solved it - I will post it as an answer